# Caching of Function Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I essentially want to write a bunch of commonly used queries in a web application of this format:

```
SELECT *
FROM secure_table
WHERE security_function(value 1, value 2) = true;
```

Value 1 and value 2 will have a limited enough range of values for the idea of caching the result of the security function to be potentially very useful in improving application performance. We would also need to be able to trigger a reset of the cache at will since some conditions would render the cached values out of date.

Is there an out of the box way of doing this with SQL Server (I believe we will be using the 2012 version)? I've had a google around and seen nothing concrete, some references to ASP.NET state but nothing concrete about what that actually involves, and some references to memcached, but that wouldn't seem to go down to function level, so doesn't seem suitable either.

EDIT:

So I would like the function to work something like this:

```
function security_function(val1, val2)  {
result = getFromCache(val1, val2)
if result is empty then
result = //do big complicated query
addToCache(val1, val2, result)
end

return result
}
```

Comment: I did see an example of doing it that way but assuming the cache is initially empty (or even if it isn't), and the main query returns thousands of rows, wouldn't that be very slow? I was really hoping there is some in-memory way of storing the cache, so that it can be accessed without having to go to the database tables themselves. For example we have a parallel Oracle based solution that can do this via package state, but I don't believe SQL server has an equivalent.

Comment: Maybe a global temp table? Honestly I am not really sure what you are trying to do here so I am kind of guessing.

Comment: All I want to do is cache the function result in memory somehow so that when the query runs it does not need to run a query within the function for every row that is returned, bearing in mind it could be thousands or tens of thousands of results. I have edited the question to try and make this clearer.

Comment: In your web app you could save the values to cookies. Then expire them at the determined time or reset on forced push.

Comment: I can't think of any efficient solution to your problem, i would go with creating a table which holds the values (save each set after `getFromCache()` is false and before `return result;`). Probably add some informations on that table too, like "created_at", "source_table" and "source_id" so you could write a Stored Proc which cleans specific sources and/or delete expired entries.

Comment: @David Scott - I'm not sure how you mean, we can't really cache this at web app level as it's the function of the query that needs caching.

Comment: @weison - Hmm, it's quite disappointing if that's the way we have to do it, it might speed up performance a bit but doing a subquery per line sounds like it might be very slow to me, I guess I'll have to do some testing round it. Incidentally the cleanup is quite easy, if somebody changes the security config we can just clear down the table, it shouldn't be something that happens often though.

Comment: With the extended question information it seems like a table is the best choice for this. Just have a table with 3 columns (val1, val2 and result). Then populate that with a procedure that passes in all possible values for val1 and val2. Your end result should be pretty fast. I would recommend not using a scalar function though as they can get really poor performance. A stored procedure is likely to perform better here.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43572/how-to-see-what-is-cached-in-memory-in-sql-server-2008 please see if this helps. You are querying off of the buffer cache in SQL Server. May not be what your looking for but it seems a table is not to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.Net you can use the cache object to store the results of the query:

in c#:

```
Results GetResults(string value1, string value2)
{
   string cacheItemName = "cacheItem-" + value1 + "-" + value2;
   if (Cache[cacheItemName] != null)
   {
      return Cache[cacheItemName];
   }
   else
   {
      var result = // do big complicated query;
      Cache.Insert(cacheItemName, result,
             null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15d),  // Expire after 15 minutes 
                   System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
      return result;

   }

}
```